# How to create and use a global variable on Mule config?

Tags: variables, mule, config

I have tried the `wrapper.conf` declaring a variable like this:

```
wrapper.java.additional.4="-Dmule.env=development"
```

So I could access the value inside any project flow like:

```
<logger message="value = #[mule.env]" level="INFO"/>
```

But it doesn’t work, so how to declare at config or something to be able to use autodeploy feature and still have the variable value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
<logger message="value = #[server.systemProperties['mule.env']]" level="INFO"/>
```

Related doc: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Reference#MuleExpressionLanguageReference-ContextObjects

Comment: Well, it worked inside a flow but i still cant use its value outside, just saw it... any clue on how to get its value, tryng to use this code: <context:property-placeholder location="#[server.systemProperties['mule.env']].properties" />

Comment: I think SpEL should work for this: `<context:property-placeholder location="#{ systemProperties['mule.env'] }.properties" />`

Answer (score 0):

This should have been a comment. The below line should work.

```
    <context:property-placeholder location="${mule.env}.properties" />
```